# Convert decimal to hexadecimal without Javascript builtin functions

Tags: javascript

Trying to convert a base 10 number to a base 16 number:

```
            var hex = []; //array for hexadecimals

            while (num > 0) { //if num greater than 0 loop will run

                hex=(num%16); //divides num by 16

                if (hex>9) {
                    if (hex==10) {
                        hex.unshift("A")
                    }
                    if (hex==11) {
                        hex.unshift("B")
                    }
                    if (hex==12) {
                        hex.unshift("C")
                    }
                    if (hex==13) {
                        hex.unshift("D")
                    }
                    if (hex==14) {
                        hex.unshift("E")
                    }
                    if (hex==15) {
                        hex.unshift("F")
                    }
                }

                if (hex<=9) {
                    hex.unshift(hex)
                }


            }

            alert("That decimal in hexadecimal is " + hex.join(''));
        }
    }
```

For whatever reason this code is not working for me... any thoughts?? I'm trying to replace 10,11,12,.. with A , B , C, ... however it doesn't seem to be working. I tried using if else statements, however when I run the code it crashes.

Comment: You're assigning `num % 16` and so forth to `hex`. I believe you mean to assign that to `num`. After all, since `hex` is an array, it can't exactly be `== 10`

Comment: I know that the title is "without Javascript built in functions", but may I ask why you don't use `toString(16)`? Why would you write code that has already been written?

Comment: @Tomasito665 Probably a homework assignment. It's a common task to rewrite existing functions for practice.

Comment: @Tomasito665 For assignment like Blex said. I have to rewrite these existing functions using my own logic. Unfortunately  my logic on coding is very limited :/

Comment: @MikeC are you saying i change my code to num=(num%16)??

Comment: Nothing in your `while` loop changes `num`.  Your loop is going to run forever.

Comment: @LA495 Yes. As RJM pointed out, you aren't even changing `num` right now so your loop will never end.

Comment: You use an array to hold what? Do you want each digit of the new hexadecimal number to be a single element in the array? Or did you want each element in the hex array to be an entire hexadecimal number?

Comment: Thank all of you! I took everything you said into account and its running perfectly now!

Answer (score 2):

In your original code you weren't updating `num` and it looks like you misunderstood how `%` works, `%` is modulus not division.

If you aren't sure how converting between bases works you can check out [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Convert-Between-base-10-Hexadecimal-and-B/) or just Google it, there are many videos and sites about the algorithm.

**JavaScript**

```
var number = 123456; //The input value
var hexCharacters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]; //Digits for 10-15, eliminates having case statements
var hexString = "";

while (number > 0) {
  var mod = number % 16; //Get the remainder
  number = Math.floor(number / 16); //Update number

  //Prepend the corresponding digit
  if (mod > 9) {
    hexString = hexCharacters[mod - 10] + hexString; //Get the digits for 10-15 from the array
  } else {
    hexString = mod.toString() + hexString;
  }
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9em01uu/)**

Comment: Could you add some comment or explanation for the `hexString = hexCharacters[mod .....` line? Thanks.

Comment: This is to get the corresponding digits for 10-15 from the array, If `mod` is 10, the code will retrieve the first element of the array (`hexCharacters[0]`), which is 'A'. If `mod` is 11, it will get the second element, (`hexCharacters[1]`), which is 'B'. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

### Quick Solution

**Add this line in your while loop somewhere after the line `hex=(num%16)`**

```
num = Math.floor(num / 16);
```

---

### Explanation

Your logic is correct, you simply forgot to (or didn't know that % didn't) divide `num` by 16.

Look at this line (line number 5 in your code):

```
hex = (num % 16);     //divides num by 16
```

It gets the remainder when num is divided by 16, and store it in hex. That is correct so far, since you'll need to know what that value is.

However, in your comment you note that the line `"divides num by 16"`. This is ***not*** quite true. It only gets what the remainder ***would*** be, ***if*** it was divided by 16. You still have to do the dividing yourself.

That can be done with this line:

```
num = Math.floor(num / 16);
```

in your while loop. Of course you'll still need the line `hex=(num%16);`. I recommend adding the new line right after your first the line `hex=(num%16);`, so its purpose is clear.

Your edited code could loop like this:

```
var hex = [];    // array for hexadecimals

while (num > 0) {    // if num greater than 0 loop will run

    hex = (num % 16);          // Gets remainder when num is divided by 16
    num = Math.floor(num / 16) // Actually divides num by 16

    if (hex > 9) {
        .
        .
        .
```

---

I recommend **amura.cxg**'s answer though, as **amura.cxg** shows a very nice way to reformat your code so that it is well-written, clear, and concise.

I only posted my answer so that I could show you exactly where your code when wrong, since I thought that information would be very helpful to you.